# Determine the length of the tube

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, flow-control, liquid, hydrostatics

I need to determine the size of the tube having the flow rate of the liquid (water) which is 5 ml/min and assuming the diameter of the tube is 4mm. How can i determine the size of the tube that takes approx one minute for 5ml water to flow along the tube?

Comment: There's a few ways to figure this out, depending on what exactly it is you care about. Is this a practical problem or a homework problem?

Answer (score 1):

If the flow rate is 5ml/min, and you want to know how long a tube it will take 1 min to pass through, you’re effectively asking how long a tube contains 5ml.

Volume of a cylinder is $\pi*r^2*h$.

5ml = 5000mm^3.

Pi*r^2 = Pi*2mm^2 = 4pi mm^2

Your length therefore is 5000/4pi or around 400mm.